# Link instances in a UML class diagram with Papyrus

Tags: papyrus

Under Papyrus 4.2.0, how can I link two instance specifications (as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JE2_7.5.5/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/clink.html) or [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#link))?

I created a new class diagram, created two `Instance Specification`s, and click on the `Link` entry in the `Edges` Palette, and when hovering over my instances, the icon says “forbidden”, as when trying to use an edge on something that can’t receive that kind of edge. This is consistent with the tooltip for `Link`, which says: `Creation of a link for comment, constraint, TimeObservation, DurationObservation`.

The bug reports [432693](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432693), [468588](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=468588), [444606](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444606), [432678](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432678) (all but the last fixed long ago) indicate that it is possible to link instances with Papyrus. But how?

The [user guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus_User_Guide) does not mention instances or links.

Comment: Found [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=360164&goto=987449&#msg_987449) post, might be the answer that I’m looking for. But it doesn’t work for me, not sure if it’s a bug.

Comment: It now works, not sure why. Might be related to bug [517689](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517689)…

Answer (score 1):

You have to have two "Instance specification" (object) for example in a class diagram. The objects have to have classifiers. The two classifier have to have at least an association to each other.
Then choose "Instance Specification" tool from the "Edges" palette. Tie them together with the mouse. When the moue button released on the target object, two new window will be opened (with papyrus 4.4.0). The first window completely empty, but the second shows a list with associations between the two classifier. Choose one, and press the "OK" button. The empty window will be remained on the screen. Close the empty window. And voila link created.

Comment: I do not currently use Papyrus any more so can’t check your answer, but thanks for your help anyway, I guess it will be useful to others.